# Storing custom objects in MongoDB Array. Embed or reference?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a collection called products which contains products like so

```
{
  "name" :
  "price" :
  "category" :
  "quality" :
}
```

and I have a user object that contains an array of products like so

```
{
  "products" : []
}
```

My question - what is the best way to go about storing "product objects" in the products array.

Do I just put the corresponding ObjectID's inside the "products" array? 
Do I literally put each "dictionary" as an entry in the products array?

The first approach would actually create a pointer so it seems the most logical, however that means that after I fetch the products array I would have to fetch each objectId from the products array and parse that.

The second option means that I wouldn't have to parse the each ObjectID, but there wouldn't be any link between the products in the product array and the product in the products collection

Any other way to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB we avoid joins and we reduce the number of collections for perfomance
and simplicity reasons.Document model allows us to do it.

But there are other things to consider

- **Are those data accessed together?** (if yes + to embed)
  for example when we need the users, we need the products also?
- **How big will be the products array?** (if not too big + to embed)
- **How often those products will be updated?** (if reraly + to embed)
  in case of embed this means that we will have to update in many locations
- **How much duplication we will have?** (if small + to embed)
  for example a product can be in 5000 customers? this means that if a product changes we need to do all those extra updates
- **Is update even needed?** (if no + to embed/duplicate)
  for example if a customer gets on its products array a product that its price changes, it might be correct to pay the price it had when he added it to his product array, so update with refence would cause wrong results
- **Do we need both collections?** (if no + to embed)
  for example if products are always accessed from the customers, maybe we can avoid having a second collection
- **Data staleness is acceptable?** (if its ok + to embed)
  for example if product price changes and and the user has in its product array
  a product with the old price is it ok?
  (this might last some milliseconds but still can be problem)
- **Is data staleness problems, fixable?**   (if its ok + to embed)
  for example lets say that the price changed and person go to pay,
  and we are so unlucky that thise milliseconds/seconds caused the problem,
  if it can detected at pay time(like find by productID and price),
  then its fixable
  if data staleness is not acceptable and not fixable then you can consider
  transactions, but in this case i think reference is better

I guess there are more creteria to think about, but i think the above are
some of the basic things.

Comment: If I go about using the second option (which is to embed the entire product into the products array), lets say that I change an Object in the products collection, will that change propagate into the User's "Product" array if they both have the same id?

Comment: no, you have to do it with application logic, see also change streams, even if you keep references, if a product is deleted, still you have to do it with application logic, mongodb doesnt do that automatically

Comment: For anyone reading this thread later, this article is quite helpful - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/, the gist of it is that if you want to relate two different documents, you "essentially" have to use ObjectID's (there are other ways if you want).

Comment: as far as i know DBrefs were used before `$lookup` and they are slow, like multiple queries, i havent used them, and i am not sure but i think this is the case